MNAR and the pyampute package
Im amputing a dataset with the pyampute package by Schouten et al. (link to their documentation: https://rianneschouten.github.io/pyampute/build/html/about.html)
I was just reading through the documentation again and was wondering if thats really the MNAR mechanism there.
For the MNAR mechanism, missingness was introduced by designating 80% of the variables in the dataset as incomplete. For the incomplete variables weights (W) are set to 1.
For each row $i$ in the dataset a weighted sum score is calculated as the dot product of the weight vector (W) and the incomplete values $X_{i,miss}$.
\begin{equation}
\text{Score}_i = \sum_{j=1}^{|X_{\text{miss}}|} W_j X^{miss}_{i,j}
\end{equation}
Using a sigmoid function the weighted sum scores are transformed into a probability $p_{i}$.
\begin{equation}
p_i = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\text{Score}_i}}
\end{equation}
For the incomplete variables $X^{miss}$ in row $i$, missingness was determined by drawing samples from a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p_i$.
\begin{equation}
M_{ij} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i) \quad \text{for } j = 1, \ldots, |X_{\text{miss}}|
\end{equation}
If $M_{ij} = 1$, then the corresponding entry $X^{miss}_{ij}$ was set to missing.
So following this method the missingness of a value depends on all the other missing values and itself.
When i look up the definition of MNAR it says that the missingness of a value only depends on the unobserved value itself. So this seems contradictory to me. Am i missing (haha :D ) something ? Or is it fine under the definition of MNAR that missingness can also depend on other non missing values ??
Thanks in advance for an answer!
Best Matthias
